# Decomposing functions on the fundamental domain of the torus into cusp forms, eisenstein series

Tags: modular-forms, harmonic-analysis, theta-functions, eisenstein-series

I am trying to do some elementary calculations to understand the properties of the following spectral resolution on $H/SL(2,\mathbf{Z})$. (Half plane mod modular group; fundamental domain of the torus)

Let $\{\nu_n\}$ be a discrete spectrum of cusp forms, except for $\nu_0$ which is just a constant. Let their eigenvalues under the laplacian be

$$\Delta \nu_n = s_n (s_n -1)\nu_n$$

where $s_n \in \frac{1}{2}+i \mathbf{R}$. Then also let's consider the continuous spectrum of Eisenstein series $E_s$ with

$$\Delta E_s = s (s-1)E_s, \quad s \in \frac{1}{2}+i \mathbf{R}.$$

The Roelke-Selberg spectral resolution says that any square-integrable function on the fundamental domain may be written as

$$f(z) = \sum_n (f,\nu_n) \nu_n + \frac{1}{4 \pi i}\int_{s\in \frac{1}{2}+i \mathbf{R}}(f,E_s) E_s$$

where the inner product is given by

$$(f,g) = \int_{H/SL(2,\mathbf{Z})}f(z)\overline{g(z)}y^{-2} \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y.$$

Now, I'd like to write a few known functions in this basis. However, I don't even know how to write down the basis functions in such a way as to actually compute the relevant integrals. For instance, what would the coefficients $(Z,\nu_n), \, (Z,E_s)$ be for

$$Z(x,y) = \left(\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{12 i \pi  (x+i y)}\right) \vartheta _3\left(0,\sqrt[24]{e^{2 i \pi
    (x+i y)}}\right)-\vartheta _3\left(0,\left(e^{2 i \pi  (x+i y)}\right)^{3/8}\right)
   \vartheta _3\left(0,\left(e^{2 i \pi  (x+i y)}\right)^{2/3}\right)\right)/(2 \eta (x+i y)^2)$$

I do not know if this is a problem that is very hard or simply uninteresting to mathematicians since the book I'm reading (Audrey Terras' *Harmonic Analysis on Symmetric Spaces*) doesn't appear to consider the issue of literally resolving particular functions into this basis.

Comment: What have tori got to do with this?

Comment: If you're asking for examples of Maass cusp forms, then you're going to be sadly disappointed. See my MSE answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989624/examples-of-maass-forms-of-sl2-mathbbz-backslash-mathbbh/2072965#2072965